# Getting data from a JSON array and setting states based on the data using loop in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Suppose, I'm getting JSON array and want to **setState** as I'm getting that array in my component.

```
        for( var follower_id = 0; follower_id < followers_data.length; follower_id++) {
          this.setState({
            followers_data_username[followers_data_username.length] = followers_data[follower_id].login
          });
          console.log(followers_data_username[0]);
        }
```

But I don't know how to set up my **getInitialState** if I'm going to use an array. Also, I don't think that I can **setState** of an array.

I'm new to React. So, any help or pointing to the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Consider the JSON to be something similar to this: https://api.github.com/users/ghoshnirmalya/followers

Comment: why are you trying to set a state for each element in the json array? that is just going to override any data from the previous row... are you trying to list out a table on the front end?

Comment: yes. i'm trying to get all the data from the json and list out a table. what will be the best way to do that?

Comment: is this es6 syntax? did you look at the react examples?

Comment: I'm trying to follow the syntax which is provided in the react tutorial (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a map function on your data like so

```
render(){
    let rows = this.state.followers_data.map( (follower, i) => <TableRow follower={follower} key={i} />);

    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

and your row component would look something like this..

```
const TableRow = (props) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{this.props.follower.login}</td>
        </tr>
    );
};
```

now this is just a basic example... you need to model it to work for your project.. but you should follow this pattern for all of the json data... you have a table and in the tbody you render rows.. which is an array of components that are generated off of each json object in the array.

Comment: What if I'm loading the JSON from another url using **onClick** function? Will this work for that scenario also?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh yes that is what I was expecting you to have.. your onClick function should call `this.setState({followers_data: whatever_your_data_is})` which will re-render the rows with whatever the data is that comes back